# nrwl with angular - how to share external library in a shared nrwl lib?

Tags: angular, typescript, module, shared-libraries, nrwl-nx

If I have dependencies such as `lodash`, `@nb-bootstrap` or `@fontawesome`, how can I share these library in a `libs/shared/` nx's lib ?

For example, I have `alert-update-modal.component.html` with errors messages saying that `'fa-icon' is not a known element`

**`libs/shared/alert/src/lib/alert-update-modal/alert-update-modal.component.html`**

```html
...
<fa-icon [icon]="'download'"></fa-icon>
<!-- 'fa-icon' is not a known element ...... -->
...
```

**`libs/shared/src/lib/shared.module.ts`**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { SharedLibsModule } from './shared-libs.module';

@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule, SharedLibsModule],
  declarations: [],
})
export class SharedModule {}
```

**`libs/shared/src/lib/shared-libs.module.ts`**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { NgJhipsterModule } from 'ng-jhipster';
import { InfiniteScrollModule } from 'ngx-infinite-scroll';
import { FontAwesomeModule } from '@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome';
import { TranslateModule } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { DragDropModule } from '@angular/cdk/drag-drop';

@NgModule({
  exports: [
    FormsModule,
    CommonModule,
    DragDropModule,
    NgbModule,
    NgJhipsterModule,
    InfiniteScrollModule,
    FontAwesomeModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    TranslateModule
  ]
})
export class SharedLibsModule {}
```